# Amcharts grid color with opacity

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

Need to change line(grid) color, create custom theme, but my line with opacity

[image]

```js
function am4themes_sdTheme(target) {
  if (target instanceof am4core.InterfaceColorSet) {
    target.setFor('text', am4core.color('#ffffff')); // text color
    target.setFor('grid', am4core.color('#ffffff')); // line color
  }
}
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_sdTheme);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be easier to target the lines using CSS selectors.

Comment: there are no classes on grid lines, by selector - not variant, but thank you

Answer (score 1):

That's a [tick](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/pieseries/#ticks_property), not a grid. You have to target it separately:

```
function am4themes_sdTheme(target) {
  if (target instanceof am4core.InterfaceColorSet) {
    target.setFor('text', am4core.color('#ffffff')); 
  }
  if (target instanceof am4charts.Tick) { 
    target.strokeOpacity = 0;
  }
}
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_sdTheme);
```

[Tick](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tick/#Inheritance) extends different types of elements, so you might want to be more specific and use PieTick if you want to differentiate between pie ticks, axis ticks, etc.

Comment: thanks for idea, resolution is if (target instanceof am4charts.Tick) { target.strokeOpacity = 1 }

Answer (score 0):

```js
function am4themes_sdTheme(target) {
  if (target instanceof am4core.InterfaceColorSet) {
    target.setFor('text', am4core.color('#ffffff')); // text color
    target.setFor('grid', am4core.color('#ffffff')); // line color
  }
  if (target instanceof am4charts.Tick) {
    target.strokeOpacity = 1; // line opacity
  }
}
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_sdTheme);
```

Comment: Please explain what is going on with your code. Some commentary that adds clarity along with your code is much better for the OP and community.